# ESLint not throwing basic errors in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, eslint, es6-class, eslintrc

Should I not be receiving `no-undef` errors for something like this, or does the possibility of inheritance throw these ESLint errors out the window when it comes to ES6 classes?

```
class SomeClass {

  constructor () {

    this.someNonExistentFunction()

  }
}
```

My `.eslintrc` if it makes a difference:

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "airbnb-base"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 9
  },
  "rules": {
    "space-before-function-paren": ["error", "always"],
    "object-curly-newline": ["error", { "consistent": true }],
    "indent": ["warn", 2, {"SwitchCase": 1}],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "semi": ["error", "never"],
    "no-console": ["warn", { "allow": ["warn", "error"] }],
    "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "never"],
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 200, "ignoreStrings": true, "ignoreComments": true, "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true }],
    "quote-props": ["error", "consistent"],
    "no-self-assign": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "padded-blocks": "off",
    "curly": "off",
    "comma-dangle": "off",
    "nonblock-statement-body-position": "off",
    "no-plusplus": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "arrow-parens": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: "Should I not be receiving no-undef errors for something like this" - no. The rule only checks for globals. If you had `someNonExistentFunction()` you'd get a warning.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But am I the only one that thinks this is a major drawback (among other things) of ES6 classes? Not being able to pick up on simple typos because every variable is scoped to `this`?

Comment: "But am I the only one that thinks this..." well I do think you guys have a club :). You could use typescript to capture this type of errors statically. Or embrace the dynamic nature of javascript and write a test.

Comment: TS example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAUD60w8AdhAC4BOArsGfBdABQCU2eBBZAFgJYQB0EJMgByJAKIAPPmWTEyAMSrFaPEi3bQAvji1A